# NTFS folder permissions traverse

Tags: file-permissions, ntfs, directory

Here is the problem

We have NTFS file server with several layers of sub-folders.
FolderA\ - User AAA should not have access
FolderA\FolderAA\ - User AAA should not have access
FolderA\FolderAA\FolderAAA - user AAA should have access

How do we do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would give user AAA "list folder" access to Folder A, and FolderAA.

You give appropriate access to FolderAAA

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is quite straightforward. Create FolderA, FolderA\FolderAA and FolderA\FolderAA\FolderAAA. Then Right-click on FolderAAA, go to Security tab, Advanced, Change Permissions, then remove the tick of "Include inheritable permissions from this object's parent". Then choose to Copy the permissions.
Now go to NTFS permissions of FolderA and untick the same checkbox, but this time choose to Remove the permissions.
I tested it and it works. The catch here is, that the user needs to type the whole address in one time, eg. E:\FolderA\FolderAA\FolderAAA.

Answer (score 0):

How do you do what? How do you assign the user the appropriate permissions and grant them access to FolderAAA?

All users have the `bypass traverse checking` user right by default, which allows them to traverse a folder structure that they don't have NTFS permissions to in order to get to a folder that they do have NTFS permissions to.

So, assign the appropriate NTFS permissions to FolderAAA for the user then give the user a shortcut to FolderAAA.